# ipod not mounting

Tags: ipod, patch

Tried to connect my iPod, but got this message:

Error mounting: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

Have seen links to this here, but beeing rather green, I don't understand much. 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/734883
 What do I do now?

The     dmesg|tail says

```
[ 2819.709437] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 3901376 4096-byte logical blocks: (15.9 GB/14.8 GiB)
[ 2819.710161] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2819.735294]  sdb: [mac] sdb1 sdb2
[ 2819.738060] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 3901376 4096-byte logical blocks: (15.9 GB/14.8 GiB)
[ 2819.738671] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2819.738688] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 2820.420130] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Bad block number requested
[ 2820.420167] hfs: unable to find HFS+ superblock
[ 2820.612140] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Bad block number requested
[ 2820.612191] hfs: unable to find HFS+ superblock
```

Comment: The error message suggest you to read error in dmesg, have you tried to watch the output of `dmesg|tail` in a terminal immediatly after you see the error message?

Comment: @fain182 I've added the output. Does that help?

Comment: doesnt look nice to me; can one re-format hd on the ipod?

Comment: I could reformat it on a windows PC, but I ain't got one, and I want to use the ipod with both mac and ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

To get the iPod to mount correctly, you first need to format it using iTunes, on a Mac or PC. After that, it should mount correctly on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I think you encountered this bug: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/1428824
Kernel developers are solving it in this days, IMHO you can just wait for a kernel update or try an older version of the kernel.